# Node : What is the right way to delete all the files from a directory?

Tags: node.js, express

So I was trying to delete all my files inside a folder using node.

I came across **2 methods** .

**Method 1**

Delete the folder using rmkdir. But if I plan on adding the images on the same folder then I use mkdir and creates the same folder again and appends the files to it.

Example: I have an `Add Files` and `Delete ALL` button. When I click `deleteAll` , the folder gets deleted. And when I click add then the folder gets created and the file gets added to that folder

**Method 2**

Using `readdir` , I loop through the files and stores in an array and then delete only the files instead of the folder.

Which is the best way to do it ? If its not among these then please advice me a better solution.

Comment: I think we should reduce using loop because for performance reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`rm` function of ShellJS](http://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#rmoptions-file--file-) will do the trick. It works as a one-liner, and it works cross-platform, and is well tested and documented. It even supports recursive deletes.

Basically, something such as:

```
const { rm } = require('shelljs');

rm('-rf', '/tmp/*');
```

(Sample code taken from ShellJS' documentation.)

Comment: What is unclear about `and it works cross-platform`?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw ShellJS documentation. It works well in all platforms.